# Distinguishing meaning of 「 庭」 and 「には」aurally

Tags: pronunciation, pitch-accent

In the sentence, 「私の家の庭には小さな池があります」 the sound 「には」 appears twice in a row. When listening but without any writing to inform interpretation, how will I know whether to interpret the first 「には」 sound as the kanji 「 庭」 or as the hiragana 「には」?

Comment: If you think that sentence is confusing then try: 庭には二羽鶏がいる

Comment: 中庭には二羽、庭には二羽鶏がいる

Comment: にわには{LHHL}にわ{HL}、うらにわには{LHHHHL}にわ{HL}、にわとりが{LHHHH}いる{LH}（庭には二羽、裏庭には二羽、鶏がいる）

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you can distinguish using the pitch accent. 庭 is pronounced like にわ【LH】 (i.e., 平板 accent) and には pronounced in isolation is にわ【HL】. 庭には is pronounced as にわにわ【LHHL】. (には within a sentence is pronounced like には【LL】 after a non-平板 word.)

When two words are pronounced exactly the same way including the pitch accent, the context is the only clue. If you can distinguish *night* and *knight*, *too* and *two*, or *their* and *there* in English conversations, the same method works in Japanese, too.

Comment: When you write things like 【LH】and 【HL】are you referring to Low-High and High-Low pitch-accents (respectively) as described here?: https://youtu.be/O6AoilGEers

Comment: @KevinFordTheSubmariner Yes, so 庭 is a 平板 (*heiban*) word. には is a particle (or more precisely two successive particles) itself, so it's pronounced like には【LL】 or には【HL】 depending on the previous word. In rare cases where には is pronounced in isolation as a word, it would be like には【HL】.